# Glassfish IDE integration

Tags: ide, glassfish, integration

I am an Eclipse user.
I am going to be using Glassfish on a project.
Is the Glassfish IDE integration substantially better in NetBeans (or some other), or is the integration the same as Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the full set of JavaEE plugins in Eclipse, it's trivial to control/deploy to glassfish. Grab the JavaEE version of Eclipse and follow the wizard for creating a new enterprise application.

Generally speaking, unless you're debugging the only intergration you really need is: start, stop, deploy. You can make almost any IDE/script/buildfile do that. Stick with the IDE you're most productive in.

Answer (score 1):

I can't compare it to eclipse because I never tried it in eclipse but I can cast my vote for Netbeans integration. I've been using it for a while with Netbeans and I am very satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with Eclipse.

Glassfish IDE integration is better with NetBeans.

The plugin for Eclipse isn't quite ready for primetime.
https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/eclipse34/

My personal experience is that Eclipse with the Java EE extensions are more than sufficient for development, and deployment of JAX-WS apps are faster in Eclipse than with Netbeans.

The Glassfish plugin has forms for editing configuration for things as nuanced as WSIT WS-Security and WS-AtomicTransaction.  This speeds configuration.  However, I've found that deploying a JAX-WS app performs ws-import more times than necessary, which doubles deployment time.